# Powershell array in array to use in Out-GridView

Tags: arrays, powershell, logging, out-gridview

I am trying to optimize how my logging file looks in an app I have developed.
I'm currently using the following code:

```
$pro_arry = @(
"V 1.0      Initial Release          7 July 2022",
"V 1.1      Optimized Update functionality and added logging         9 July 2022"
)
```

it looks like such:

[image]

I would like to use something like a nested array in order to display the Version, Description, and Date in separate cells.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]As formatted, this is all just one long string. Hence the results you are getting. You have to format each into their own property (thus column). OGV does a few neat things, but not everything. In those cases, you need to develop a code block or your own GUI.

OGV expects columnar data, just like databases and spreadsheets.

For example:

```
Clear-Host 
$pro_arry = @(
"V 1.0      Initial Release          7 July 2022",
"V 1.1      Optimized Update functionality and added logging         9 July 2022"
)

# Replace spaces with a comma and convert to csv with custom headers.
$pro_arry -replace '     *',',' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv -Header Version,Description,Date | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Product List' -PassThru
```